# How do i change the position of notification css html?

Tags: html, css, angular

i have two examples of notification in angular, i would like change the notifiation position display of the first example to "top right" in the screen like the second example by keeping the style and the colour of the first example and just change the position od displaying.
example 1: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2-7-notifications

example 2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-notifications-in-containers
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
.toast_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 25;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

to

```
.toast_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 25;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 450px;
}
```